# Does a boilerplate legal disclaimer protect authors of content on a website?

Tags: united-states, internet

Specifically, if the website itself has legal disclaimers to protect itself from litigation arising from legal advice provided on it, would a similar disclaimer claiming to disclaim authors of content on the website protect those authors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A disclaimer claiming to disclaim authors of content on the website can/cannot protect those authors depending upon:

1. Visibility of the Disclaimer on the website
2. On whether it can be proved that the disclaimer was included intentionally to be brought into the user's notice.
3. Location of the dispute.
4. In United States many courts have ruled in favor of the disclaimers if the were strategically placed not to be missed by the user.
5. In European Union on the other hand there is a directive which strikes down legal obligations which have been imposed and this would make disclaimers unenforceable.

For more information, please refer [This Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_disclaimer)